# Create enumeration with fields in XML schemes

Tags: xml, jaxb, enumeration

I need the equivalent of this :

```
public Enum myEnum {
  A(1),
  B(2),
  C(3)
}
```

in XML schemes, if it's possible. I know how to create simple enums:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="A"></xsd:enumeration>
        <xsd:enumeration value="B"></xsd:enumeration>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C"></xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

but for the first one, I've no idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you used maven plugin

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

you have to change the xsd in

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="1"></xsd:enumeration>
        <xsd:enumeration value="2"></xsd:enumeration>
        <xsd:enumeration value="3"></xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

and use an XJB file for bindings

```
        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='myEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='1']">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="A" />
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='myEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='2']">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="B" />
        </bindings>

        <bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='myEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='3']">
            <typesafeEnumMember name="C" />
        </bindings>
```

should generate this enum

```
@XmlEnum
public enum MyEnum{

    @XmlEnumValue("1")
    A("1"),
    @XmlEnumValue("2")
    B("2"),
    @XmlEnumValue("3")
    C("3");
    private final String value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunualy, I need an integer as value, so "1" doesn't work for me. Plus, I would like to avoid use XJC and extra binding files. I was thinking about something like "unions" to put  in my xsd, but I'm not sure it generates what I'm looking for.